# Insert fails on db2 database (on iSeries)

Tags: sql, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

We are having trouble inserting records into a file/table on an iSeries from our VB.NET 2010 application.

The old system running on Windows Xp has no problems but we are trying to run the code (insode VS 2010) on a Windows 7 64-bit box, and OS400 V5.4

Here is the error message returned by the driver:

```
ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token 2014 was not valid. Valid tokens: ) ,.
```

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
sConStr = "Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};" & _
    "System=" & sAS400Server & ";" & _
    "Uid=" & UCase(sAS400UserName) & ";" & _
    "Pwd=" & UCase(sAS400UserPwd) & ";" & _
    "DBQ=" & UCase$(sAS400Library) & _
    IIf(Trim$(sLibraryOther) <> "", "," & sLibraryOther, "") & _
        ";COMPRESSION=1;ALLOWUNSCHAR=1;TRANSLATE=1;"

conOdbc = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConStr)
conOdbc.Open()
```

We create out INSERT statement which looks like this:

```
"INSERT INTO kerry.YSEPF(YSESID, YSESAN, YSESCC, YSECCY, YSENEGP, YSEAMA, YSESPOD, YSEVFR, YSESNAR, YSELMBY, YSELMPC, YSECRBY, YSECRPC) VALUES (0002109416, 12345678, PS , GBP, C, 000000000006851, 1140918, 1140831, August 2014 Fuel for Co.van                                 , N , 'profile  ','DPVO           ','profile  ','DPVO           ')"
```

Then we try to insert as below:

```
iSubmitItems += 1
Try
    iRetVal = cmdOdbc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        iSubmitItemsSuccess += 1
 Catch ex As Exception
     iSubmitItemsFail += 1
```

and every time we get the error message.

Is there something we are missing such as the driver (is it a 32-bit driver but installed in a different place on Win64?)

**EDIT**
Just wanted to mention that also, the target files is packed or compressed, this is why we can't FTP the data in fixed length text format, whish is what we do for some other data imports

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid:

```
[..snip...]6851, 1140918, 1140831, August 2014 Fuel for Co.van   [...snip...]
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Strings must be encapsulated in quotes, e.g.

```
[..snip...]6851, 1140918, 1140831, 'August 2014 Fuel for Co.van'   [...snip...]
                                   ^---------------------------^---
```

And given this trivial/beginner error, I'm going to say that you're also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Note that there's more strings in the OP's code than just `'August 2014 Fuel for Co.van'`  However, the reason the DB threw the error on the 2014 is that DB2 for i supports implicit casting.  So the one word strings, `'PS'`,`'GBP'` were implicitly cast to `CHAR`.  It wasn't until it got to the mutli-word string that the DB wasn't sure what to do.  Best practice is to explicitly quote your strings.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I completely missed that in my 15 minutes of shouting at the iSeries behind the wall and screaming over and over again **it's SQL damn you, accept it**

Comment: agree about the SQL Injection thing, but it's a closed network... as I understand it, our inserts go onto the iSeries Message Queue, then another program written in control language does it's thing to load the records into the file.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's a closed network. an injection attack is any form of "external" data causing unwanted behavior in your query. you can easily inject yourself. while it may not be a classic bobby-tables `; drop table students --` type thing, it WILL most likely cause syntax errors at the very least.

Comment: thanks Marc, you are correct, the best way I guess is to put it on the message queue which is what some other systems do - trouble is in this instance I'm trying to solve a problem with an existing system being migrated to work on a new Win64 box. It will only be used by the Data Processing guys...and they have control of the iSeries and all its files. I think when this need to import data from the Sage banking system into the iSeries first came up about 8 years ago for some reason they decided to the easy but less robust or secure route

Comment: @Philip If you're running a SQL INSERT statement, we can almost guarantee that the data is being inserted into a database table, not a message queue. It's not clear how a message queue would somehow become involved with movement of the data inserted by your process.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your INSERT statement. You are missing quotes around some of the values. I am not sure of the data types of your columns, so I am going to assume they are all varchar.

This:

```
"INSERT INTO kerry.YSEPF(YSESID, YSESAN, YSESCC, YSECCY, YSENEGP, YSEAMA, YSESPOD, YSEVFR, YSESNAR, YSELMBY, YSELMPC, YSECRBY, YSECRPC) VALUES (0002109416, 12345678, PS , GBP, C, 000000000006851, 1140918, 1140831, August 2014 Fuel for Co.van                                 , N , 'profile  ','DPVO           ','profile  ','DPVO           ')"
```

Should be something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO kerry.YSEPF(YSESID, YSESAN, YSESCC, YSECCY, YSENEGP, YSEAMA, YSESPOD, YSEVFR, YSESNAR, YSELMBY, YSELMPC, YSECRBY, YSECRPC) VALUES ('0002109416', '12345678', 'PS' , 'GBP', 'C', '000000000006851', '1140918', '1140831', 'August 2014 Fuel for Co.van', 'N' , 'profile','DPVO','profile','DPVO')"
```

Comment: Thanks I will check when I get back into the office